# Let $G$ be a finite group such that $|G| = p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group such that $|G| = p$ where $p$ is  prime. Let $g,h$ be elements of $G$. What are the possible orders of $\langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle$?

My current thought: I know if $\langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle = m$, $g|m$, and $h|m$, but how can I determine $g$ and $h$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $\langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle$?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Well, it's the intersection of two subgroups of $G$, hence it's a subgroup of $G$. What does Lagrange's theorem tell you?

Comment: I see! |G| must divide the order of the subgroup. But can this subgroup has order p? or it has to be smaller than p (only left the choice of 1)?

Comment: The number of members of a subgroup of any finite group $G$ must be a divisor of $ |G|.$ (Lagrange's Theorem). So if $|G|$ is prime than a subgroup of $ G$  is either all of $G$ or contains only the identity element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$ \because G$ is cyclic of prime order $p$ , for each divisor $k$ of $p$, $G$ has exactly one subgroup of order $k$

Here $1$ and $p$ are are the only divisors, $k=1\;\text{or}\;p$

$H=\langle  g \rangle \cap \langle  h \rangle $ is a subgroup of $G$, so $\vert H \vert=1$ or $p$

---

Note that if $g=e$ or $h=e$, then  $\langle  g \rangle \cap\langle  h \rangle=\{e\}$ otherwise $\langle  g \rangle \cap\langle  h \rangle=G$